# Array of bools to ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have this array (let's call it my_array) which comes from applying numpy.any:

```
my_array
array([[ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       ...,
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Is there a way to convert this array to a ndarray? I mean, how can I see this:

```
array([[ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       ...,
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]],dtype=bool)
```

Comment: What does `my_array.dtype` output ?

Comment: the output is: `dtype('bool')`

Comment: I don't understand your problem then? You already have an `ndarray` of bools ?

Comment: shouldn't it be a `numpy.ndarray` class? It gives me a `<numpy.bool>` class.

Comment: What is the output of `type(my_array)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you show something like that to the IDE, it uses `repr(obj)`, which creates a string representation of the object. Ideally this also means `eval(repr(object)) == object`. The reason why you don't see the `dtype=bool` part is that an array comprised fully of booleans is unambiguously boolean. Likewise, an integer array is by default of dtype int32, so that is also excluded. But if you have an integer of some other type, then it will be shown.

```
>>> np.array([1, 2])
array([1, 2])
>>> np.array([1, 2]).dtype
dtype('int32')
>>> np.array([1, 2], dtype=np.uint8)
array([1, 2], dtype=uint8)
```

Your result is already in the output you want. And the docs for [numpy.any](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) confirm that:

```
Returns
-------
any : bool or ndarray
    A new boolean or `ndarray` is returned unless `out` is specified,
    in which case a reference to `out` is returned.
```

But if you want to make sure everything is right, you can check `type(my_array)` and `my_array.dtype` (assuming the object is a numpy array).

```
>>> a = np.any([[1, 2], [3, 4]], axis=0)
>>> a
array([ True,  True])
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> a.dtype
dtype('bool')
```

Comment: What a detailed answer, thank you very much @Reti43!